# php separate multilingual array and show in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I add array to `mysql` database for multilingual(`2` and `1` is language id in array) data like this:

```
{
"2":[
{"title":"french title one","address":"french title one"},
{"title":"french title two","address":"french title two"},
{"title":"french title three","address":"french title three"}
],
"1":[
{"title":"english title one","address":"english title one"},
{"title":"english title two","address":"english title two"},
{"title":"english title three","address":"english title three"}
]
}
```

in `print_r` i see this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => french title one
                    [address] => french address one
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => french title two
                    [address] => french address two
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => french title three
                    [address] => french address three
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => english title one
                    [address] => english address one
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => english title two
                    [address] => english address two
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => english title three
                    [address] => english address three
                )

        )

)
```

Now I have language id like this:

```
$language_id = 1;
```

I need to show loop(`foreach`) of data array only for language id `1` like this:

```
 <a href="english title one">english address one</a>
 <a href="english title two">english address two</a>
 <a href="english title three">english address three</a>
```

how do can i `separate` multilingual array?!

Comment: I see the "requirements dump", but no evidence of a coding attempt or research.  This is why I have DV'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy - `$array` it is your php array

```
foreach($array[1] as $val){ echo"<a href='$val[title]'>$val[address]</a>";}

/* more flexible */

$language_id = 1;
$href = 'title';
$txt = 'address';
foreach($array[$language_id] as $val){  echo"<a href='$val[$href]'>$val[$txt]</a>";}
```

If you need only a part - loop this part only.